# How to apply the layer of sigmoid function in neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python

I saw an article [How to build a simple neural network in 9 lines of Python code](https://medium.com/technology-invention-and-more/how-to-build-a-simple-neural-network-in-9-lines-of-python-code-cc8f23647ca1) and want to reconstruct the result in Mathematica. I tried the below codes:-

```
input = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}};
output = {0, 1, 1, 0};
asso = Thread[input -> output];
trained = NetTrain[LinearLayer[], asso]
trained[{1, 0, 0}]
```

The output is `0.577605`, which is far away from the result of the Python code (e.g. 0.999937). How can I modify the code to have a more similar approach/result?

In the Python article, they are using sigmoid function as the layer. I want to do it in a similar way and to replace `LinearLayer[]` (replacement of `ElementwiseLayer[Sigmoid]` doesn't work), but I'm not sure how to do.

How can I get it done? Many thanks!

**The question:-**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
input = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}};
output = {0, 1, 1, 0};
asso = Thread[input -> output];
net = NetChain[{LinearLayer[], ElementwiseLayer["Sigmoid"]}]
trained = NetTrain[net, asso]
trained[{1, 0, 0}]
(*0.995993*)
```